# Sending Android logs to logging service

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-log

I'm writing an android app in kotlin, and using the standard `Log` class to write logs throughout my code. For example `Log.e(...)`, `Log.i(...)` and so on. Sometimes I want to examine those logs, but I don't have access to the device.

Is there a standard way, or a library, where i can configure a destination for the logs?
So they will be sent to my logging service like logz.io, newrelic, AWS cloudwatch, or my own backend?

Comment: just create a wrapper class that sends the log message to your server or write logs to a file then send the log file to your server so you are not hammering the server with log messages

Comment: Yeah, use timber: https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber

Comment: Are you talking about logging in a test environment or from apps that are installed on your customers phones?

Comment: @Robert My app is for company internal use, so you can say it's for the customer phones - but the devices are company owned.